# How do I build titanium apps from the command line and invoke the simulator?

Tags: ios, netbeans, ios-simulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have always used NetBeans to develop titanium applications and used Titanium Developer to build/run them. Now that Titanium Developer is no longer supported and we need to use Titanium Studio I've found this to be less than a pleasant experience.

I created a NetBeans PHP application for a Titanium application, this gives me better JavaScript support and IMHO a cleaner environment.

I would like to be able to create an ant task to build the titanium application and also fire off the emulator launching the built application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the command line interface? That should be able to do everything you need from your ANT task 
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Titanium+Command+Line+Interface